# If $| X | \leq K$ and $| Y | \leq K$, then how can I show that $| X-Y | \leq 2K$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $|X| \leq K$ and $|Y| \leq K$, then how can I show that $|X-Y| \leq 2K$? It seems very obvious intuitively but I am not able to use the triangle inequality here. Does anyone have any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Why cann't you use the triangle inequality?

Comment: @Hetebrij Yes he can!

Comment: If you cannot (are not allowed to) use the triangle inequality, you will in effect have to prove the triangle inequality.

Comment: @user60589 No, we can, but I want to understand why user136503 thinks he is not able to use the triangle inequality. Or if it is forbidden by some power.

Comment: try to use the triangle inequality with $|X+(-Y)|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that $|x-y| \leq |x| + |y|$ since $|x-y| = |x + (-y)| \leq |x| + |(-y)| = |x| + |y|$ according to the triangle inequality.

Therefore, if we suppose that for arbitrary real numbers $x, y,$ and $k$ the inequalities $|x| \leq k$ and $|y| \leq k$ are true, then

$$|x-y| \leq |x| + |y| \leq 2\cdot k \implies |x-y| \leq 2 \cdot k$$

as desired.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

$$|X - Y| \le |X| + |Y| \le K + K = 2K$$

Comment: Reproducing (after faulty versions) @Benedict's answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/533592)

Comment: @IanMiller I don't have a new question. Me saying 'I think' was because I found this a little too easy. It seemed like a simple application of the triangle inequality. I found the question kind of strange consider user136503 has posted a lot of advanced probability problems